# Printing ABS on Ender 3 V2, and stopping part cooling fan?

Tags: creality-ender-3, abs

I want to print ABS on Ender 3 V2 so I turned off the part cooling fan.
In doing so the electronics fan stopped, apparently they are connected and I don't want to mess with the wiring.

Is it safe to run the printer with the electronics cooling fan off for long hours?

Comment: Probably not a good idea, the electronics fan is there for a reason. Please [edit] the question and state *how* you turned of the fan... via the UI, firmware, config change, unplugged (unlikely as you state that you don't want to mess with the wiring).

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the firmware or the particular board revision in your printer. The electronics fan should either be always-on or switched separately from the part-cooling fan.

Comment: turned the part cooling fan from the slicer

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put additional info in the question and *not* in the comments. Also, if possible, can you also post the board revision number and firmware and the firmware version number?